# The sum of all bigrams that start with a particular word must be equal to the unigram count for that word?

Tags: nlp

In [this](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/Engineering/CS-224N/asset/slp4.pdf) chapter (at the end of page 4) of a stanford book on natural language processing it says:

> The sum of all bigrams that start with a particular word must be equal to the unigram count for that word.

The book leaves why this is the case as an exercise to the reader but I don't understand why this would be true.
For example in the following corpus:

- A ball is red.
- All balls are red.

As far as I understand the word red would occur twice in unigrams however not appear at all as the first element of a bi-gram?

Am I missing something like that the end of sentence is used as a token? (but then the problem reemerges for trigrams?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read note 2 at the end of page 4 of the cited document, it states that:

> We need the end-symbol to make the bigram grammar a true probability distribution.

Reading the page in question, it also appears clear that the author is performing the grouping in ngrams by taking into account start and end-symbols for each sentences, that are called, respectively, `<s>` and `<\s>`.

If you compute the unigram and bigram distribution in the two sentences you provided as an example, you should thus first add the start and end symbols, then group by unigrams and bigrams, and then verify wether `len(bigram[red]) == len(unigram[red])`

If you use as regex `'w+'`, and add the start and end symbols that the author suggests, the two example sentences would then be tokenized as follows:

```
'<s>', 'A', 'ball', 'is', 'red', '<\s>'
'<s>', 'All', 'balls', 'are', 'red', '<\s>'
```

The bigrams that start with 'red' are ('red', '<\s>') in sentence 1 and again ('red', '<\s>') in sentence 2, for 2 bigrams in total. The unigrams that contain 'red' are ('red') in sentence 1 and again ('red') in sentence 2, for two unigrams in total.
The total number of unigrams containing 'red' thus coincides with the number of bigrams whose first element is 'red'.

Comment: Does that not then push the problem on when using trigrams?

Comment: I tried to compute for higher dimensionality of ngrams, and it may be the case that if you want the ngrams containing 'word' to have the same absolute frequency of the unigrams containing 'word', you need to add n-1 end tokens to each string. I would like to see a theoretical explanation of this though, if anybody can provide it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The original claim is not exactly right unless you include bigrams like `<'red', '.'>` or `<'red', '_EOS_'>`.